# I keep getting java.lang.NumberFormatException:For input string:""

Tags: java, string

I was trying to return 4 values two of which are string. But I keep on getting the NumberFormatException. This is the portion where the error is coming from.

```
try{
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Butch\\Desktop\\Database\\StudentBase.sqlite");
    PreparedStatement statement=connection.prepareStatement(("select FirstName+LastName,GradeLevel,ReadingLevel from Student where FirstName=? AND LastName=? AND GradeLevel=? AND ReadingLevel=?"));
    statement.setString(1,textField.getText());
    statement.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(textField_3.getText()));
    statement.setInt(3,Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText()));
    ResultSet resultset=statement.executeQuery();
    while(resultset.next())
    {
    textField.setText(resultset.getString(1));
    textField_3. setText(Double.toString(resultset.getInt(2)));
    textField_2. setText(Double.toString(resultset.getInt(3)));
    }

}

}
catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Is there a way to rewrite it?

Comment: The error happens because you try to turn an empty String into a number. The line number should tell you exactly where that happens.

Answer (score -1):

Try: changing this:

```
statement.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(textField_3.getText()));
statement.setInt(3,Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText()));
```

To this:

```
statement.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt("0"+textField_3.getText()));
statement.setInt(3,Integer.parseInt("0"+textField_2.getText()));
```